# Course indication for community databricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I need to learn how to use databricks, using the Python programming language. Does anyone have any introductory course tips that teach how to use the Databricks community (which is free), where I can use the Python language?

Any tips swill be appreciated!

Comment: maybe you can start with: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/beginners-guide-on-databricks-spark-using-python-pyspark-de74d92e4885

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a lot of tutorials, you can find many stuffs googling some keywords, like databricks community, python, ....

Here are some options, that in my opinion is friendly:

1. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/beginners-guide-on-databricks-spark-using-python-pyspark-de74d92e4885;
2. https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-databricks-analyzing-covid-19-1194d833e90f;
3. https://hevodata.com/learn/databricks-python/.

In these tutorials an easy-to-understand language is used. The first steps are also detailed here.